# Create Rows depending on count in Informatica

Tags: informatica-powercenter

I am new to informatica power center tool and performing some assignment.
I have input data in a flat file.

```
        data.csv contains
        A,2
        B,3
        C,2
        D,1
```

And Required output will be

```
        output.csv should be like
        A
        A
        B
        B
        B
        C
        C
        D
```

Means I need to create output rows depending upon value in column. I tried it using java transformation and I got the result.

Is there any other way to do it.
Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Java transformation is a very good approach, but if you insist on an alternative implementation, you can use a helper table and a Joiner transformation.

1. Create a helper table and populate it with appropriate amount of rows (you need to know the maximum value that may appear in the input file).
   There is one row with `COUNTER=1`, two rows with `COUNTER=2`, three rows with `COUNTER=3`, etc.
2. Use a Joiner transformation to join data from the input file and the helper table - since the latter contains multiple rows for a single `COUNTER` value, the input rows will be multiplied.

```
COUNTER
-------------
1
2
2
3
3
3
4
4
4
4
(...)
```

Depending on your RDBMS, you may be able to produce the contents of the helper table using a SQL query in a source qualifier.

Comment: yes java transformation is good approach. creating helper table is kind of static one.

Comment: is it possible by using normalizer.

Comment: @user3013022 No, I think the Normalizer transformation always produces the same amount of output rows for every input row.

Comment: @user3013022 If you like the Java solution, why are you looking for a different one?

Comment: You can find detailed description here: http://powercenternotes.blogspot.com/2013/02/multiplying-rows-with-java.html